# What is the difference between gets() and getc()?

Tags: c, string.h

I try to input a string in `char ch[20]`, I want when I press space key then it will stop to take input into the variable. But the `gets()` function takes input as long as I don't press enter key. How can I take input as long as I don't press space character?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question title is not the same as the question you are asking. Also please try to give the textual presentation of your question more care, there are edit buttons to help you formatting things better.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `gets`, it has been removed from the C standard because it is inherently unsafe. Use `fgets`, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gets()` is no more a standard and it might lead to buffer overflow so you should use `fgets()` in-order to read till end of line . In order to read char by char until you encounter space you can use `getc()` as shown below.

Check the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    char a[20];
    while(((ch = getc(stdin)) != ' ') && i<19)
    a[i++] = ch;
    a[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` can be 20 when execution reaches `a[i] = '\0';` ,thus leading to Undefined Behavior